# Why is my dictionary being wiped after adding to it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, dictionary

Currently working through the 'Automate the Boring Stuff' python tutorial and was completing an exercise at the end of the tutorial section.

I'm finding that when I add the information from a list into the main dictionary it works, but then after the function completes it seems to wipe the dictionary's contents.

```
inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}

def addToInventory(dict, addedItems):
    
    for i in addedItems:
        if i not in dict:
            dict[i] = 1
        else:
            dict[i] = dict[i] + 1
        print(dict) #this exists so that I could check it wasn't a weird thing in the definition

def displayInventory(inventory):
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        print(v, k)
        item_total += v
    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))


dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)

displayInventory(inv) #the dictionary appears as empty
```

Comment: `inv` is going to be `None` because you never return anything from `addToInventory`. You're modifying `inv` and it's a mutable `dict`, so you could just do `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)`(note that there's no `inv =`) and then `displayInventory(inv)` should work. Also, suggestion, don't call your argument to `addToInventory` `dict` - `dict` is a built-in Python keyword so that method would shadow the built-in name.

Comment: Your `addToInventory` function doesn't return anything (hence it returns `None` implicitly), and then you assign that return value to `inv` after you call it.  Just remove the `inv =` from that second to last line.

Comment: I think the simplest way (least keystrokes) would be to double click on the `inv` in the `inv =` at the bottom, in order to highlight it, and then replace the variable there with just an underscore `_`.

Comment: `dict` is the name of a built-in type. It is best not to use that as a function argument name. It will "shadow" (make invisible) the type inside the fuction!

Answer (score 3):

`addToInventory` doesn't return anything, so `inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)` causes inv to be None. What you want instead is to just call `addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)`, which updates inv.

Answer (score 0):

A minor note for code refactoring purposes. I noticed that in your func `addToInventory`, there exists the following logic:

```
if i not in dict:
    dict[i] = 1
else:
    dict[i] = dict[i] + 1
```

That could actually, be simplified just a little bit:

```
dict[i] = dict.get(i, 0) + 1
```

Or again a little further, using a `defaultdict`:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


def addToInventory(dict, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        dict[i] += 1
        print(dict)  # this exists so that I could check it wasn't a weird thing in the definition


inv = defaultdict(int, **{'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1})
```

But now on to the meat of the issue you were actually noticing / asking about. As indicated in the comments, that can be resolved in one of two ways. One approach could be to simply add a `return` statement at the end of the function body:

```py
def addToInventory(dict, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        if i not in dict:
            dict[i] = 1
        else:
            dict[i] = dict[i] + 1
    # --> ADD this, here
    return dict
```

Or simply, without the `return` statement:

```py
# return value is None, but let's say we still want to capture the `None` value
_ = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
```